# What is good way to modify (add a number to every byte) a binary file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, binary, decode

I have an encoded file whose bytes are off by some number. I want to add that number to every byte in the file to decode it. But doing so by manually adding number to every single byte in a hex editor is very time-consuming and not efficient.

It looks like *bbe* can be right tool to do it, but I'm not sure how to use it well. Is there a tool that has a feature to add/delete/modify a binary file block by block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr \\000-\\376 \\001-\\377  <input >output
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you going to do with 0xFF?

You might be able to with [tr](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr%201), but it would probably be easier to write a little Python script.

In Python:

```
with open('in', 'rb') as f:
    with open('out', 'wb') as g:
        for x in f.read():
            g.write(''.join([ chr((ord(a)+1) % 256) for a in x]))
```

Comment: I think I can write a script to do that, just wondering if there's any tools are available

Comment: I ended up writing just little c program to do it but thanks for help.